# Are there any side effects of using Mutators?

Tags: streets-of-rogue

Apparently you can make the game easier or harder through Mutators, through Hacker on home base. Are there any adverse effects of using them? Like not being able to earn achievements or such? I saw nothing really stated in the game, but would rather be sure before trying it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes (kinda)**

If you use the sandbox mutator, you won't be able to unlock characters (and therefore unlock achievements) or earn chicken nuggets. Any other mutator than that, however, doesn't seem to block anything.